# Stop reloading page with 'Enter Key'

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a search box at the top of page that makes an ajax call when a user hits the adjacent button. I am trying to update the input tag so that when a user hit the *'enter' key*, the apropriate JavaScript takes place *without* reloading the page. The problem is that the page keeps reloading. Here is my latest attempt:

```
$("searchText").bind('keyup', function(event){ 
  if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#buttonSrch").click(); 
    return false;
  }
});

<input type='search' id='searchText' />
<input type='button' id='buttonSrch' onclick="search(document.getElementById('searchText'))" value='Search' />
```

Comment: Does your `search()` function have a `return false` as well?

Comment: Please don't edit out mistakes in your question as answers point them out - that makes the answers look wrong :)

Comment: fudgey, I tried adding 'return false;' to the search function as you suggested, but the page still reloads.

Comment: I think your question only applies when <input> is inside <form> tag.  Without enclosing <form> tag, 'enter' does not reload page. Also, jquery 'return false' does event.preventDefault(). So you don't need both.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/eYzSX/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't bind to the `input`s; bind to the `form`. Assuming the `form` has an ID of `searchForm`:

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function() {
    search($("#searchText").get(0));
    return false;
});
```

**[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/YC6UD/)**

It can also be done with plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    search(document.getElementById('searchText'));
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: Hmmm, in the previous version the submit and input field was never within a form tag. Maybe this is the problem. I will try...

Comment: I tried... no success. $("#searchForm").submit(function() {
  search($("#searchText").get(0));
  return false;
});  
...
<form id='searchForm'>
  <input type='search' id='searchText' />
  <input type='button' id='buttonSrch' onclick="search(document.getElementById('searchText'))" value='Search' />
</form>

Comment: @John: I added an example on JSFiddle to my answer. It works for me.

Comment: locally, no: <!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
   function search(input) {
    $('<p>').text('searching for '+input.value).appendTo('body');
   }

   $("#searchForm").submit(function() {
    search($("#searchText").get(0));
    return false;
   }); 
  }
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>

 <form id="searchForm" action="search" method="post">
  <input type="search" id="searchText" name="query" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @John: Your local example is missing a `);` at the end of the script. As is, it looks like this: `$(document).ready(function() { }`. Once that is fixed, it works for me.

Comment: Sorry about that icktoofay , I must be getting tired.  Thank you very nuch ... up voted.

Comment: The problem with this solution is when we have a grid with more than one value that we want to save... is there a way to find which input triggered the submit?

Comment: @Kremena: Add a parameter to the anonymous function. This will be an event object. You can get at the element which triggered the event by accessing the `target` property of the event. Keep in mind that this will be a plain DOM element—you will need to wrap it into a jQuery object if you want it that way.

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing and posted my solution once I got it working.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you mind adding a jsfiddle to your answer that does the same thing but with plain javascript?

Comment: @Musixauce3000: I translated the code in my answer to not use jQuery. The rest of the functionality in the fiddle can be translated too if necessary.

Answer (score 23):

I know its a little late but I ran into the same problem as you. It worked for me using "keypress" instead of bind.

```
$('#searchText').keypress(function (e) {                                       
       if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //do something   
       }
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach but my form was still submitting and the page was getting refreshed.

Answer (score 19):

Add `onSubmit="return false;"` on your form tag

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">
/* form elements here */
</form>`
```

Comment: didn't even have to listen to key events. this alone fixed it.+1

Comment: I had same problem on a page with lots of Bootstrap 4 forms which did not have type="submit" buttons but, instead, had type="button" buttons. The page was getting reloaded whenever enter key was pressed when cursor was inside any input text field inside those forms. This solution of adding `onSubmit="return false;"` to the form tags fixed the problem.

Comment: This just prevents it from working on svelte

Answer (score 16):

You are missing `#` in the selector. Try this

```
<input type='text' id='searchText' />
```

JS

```
$("#searchText").bind('keyup', function(event){ 
  if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    //$("#buttonSrch").click(); 
    search(this.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Good catch ShankarSangoli, I thumbed up. Unfortunately, I corrected this error and it still does not work. The above is the latest in several attempts actually.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `search` input type. It was added in HTML5.

Comment: @icktoofay - Thanks for that I was not aware of it.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - I tried it (and a few variations). Still not working.

Comment: Note that `return false` includes `preventDefault()` already.

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('#seachForm').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //do something
 });
```

Comment: I agree with @icktoofay, but this is a cleaner way of going about in imho. You should bind to the <form> element. If you don't have a form element on your page, I question why hitting enter is having an effect as the browser will no know where to post.

Comment: In my case, I absolutely had to prevent the form being submitted if the user hits enter because the engine would redirect it to who knows where (Google Apps Script HTML template). `preventDefault()` did the trick.

Comment: you can even generalize it as: $('form').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault()});

Answer (score 5):

You could set the form action attribute to javascript:void(0); that way the form doesn't post/get so the page wont refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form1').attr('action', 'javascript:void(0);');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the "action" attribute in `<form>` tag.
Like this

```
<form action="#">   // your content     </form>
```

Comment: That'll still make the page reload.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("searchText").keypress(function(event){ 
  if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
    $("#buttonSrch").click(); 
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: @PareshMangukiya A small tip: in comments, writing `[answer]` will auto-expand to that link. Example: [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Does your JS execute immediately or on document ready?  If it's not in a document ready the button won't exist at the time you're trying to call `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me. Please note that my struggle was to find the object that triggered the form submit:

```
$('#missingStaff').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var comment = $(document.activeElement)[0];
submitComments(comment);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="search">
```

whatever function is triggered for search. When I press that search button `search()` func is triggered. That is why: @submit.prevent="search"

```
async search() {
  let yuyu = document.getElementById('search').value
  console.log('lsd', yuyu)
  try {
    let newRecipes = await this.$axios.$get(
      `/api/videosset/?user=&id=&title=${yuyu}&price=&category=`
    )
    this.$store.commit('CHANGE_NAV_LAYOUT', newRecipes)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
},
```