# How to prevent reload when enter key was pressed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET + C# + Javascript and I'm using a barcode scanner to read barcode in labels.

This scanner have a auto "Enter" when finish to read, but in my application, every time I press enter key, the page reload and return to main view.

I have a function to disable the enter key, but I need to use in a specific page like a trigger and when the scanner finish, or the enter is pressed, call the Button_Click event.

This is my function to disable the enter key:

```
<%--Script Disable Key Enter--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').keypress(function (e) {
            var code = null;
            code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            return (code == 13) ? false : true;
        });
    });
</script>
<%--end function--%>
```

Remember, I'm using a scanner to read barcodes and after read, it "press" enter key and I need to use this event "press" to call another function, a Button_Click.

---

Have a possible duplicate, but the other question don't solve my problem.
After tried to use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=SSCC_barcodeReader.ClientID%>").keypress(function () {
            $("#<%=BarCodeReader.ClientID%>").click();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The page still submit after press any key of the keyboard.
Then I'm developed a solution for my problem too simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=SSCC_barcodeReader.ClientID%>").keypress(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code == 13) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#<%=BarCodeReader.ClientID%>").click();
                }, 500)
                clearTimeout(setTimeout);
            }
        })
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The first part I get the keypress event in my TextBox then I verify if the key pressed is ENTER and execute the *.click* after 500 miliseconds, because my scanner send a confirmation before the complete typing.

The second part is to prevent to return to initial page.

Comment: that isn't default behaviour so I'm guessing you have some other code interfering here. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Please, share a complete example, code, Etc to hep you :-).

Comment: bind an event to your form submit and prevent the default action so you can do what you want without the page reloading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop reloading page with 'Enter Key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866053/stop-reloading-page-with-enter-key)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have seen this post and do not resolve my problem. Because this I created a new one.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and explain how you used the answer, and how it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with two functions.
Now my application is usefully that I want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=SSCC_barcodeReader.ClientID%>").keypress(function () {
            $("#<%=BarCodeReader.ClientID%>").click();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code works for me to prevent page load on enter key press

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code as in OP's question (see the last part).