# Avoid a link to reload the page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, reload

I am having this button in an `<a>` tag (would like to keep it in an a tag).

```html
<center><a href="javascript:changePassword()" type="button" id="box_button" class="pw-button">Change Password</a></center>
```

The problem is that when I hit Enter the password gets changed, unfortunately the page reloads, which would be very annoying, when it comes to UX. So, how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Well, I figuered out, that the problem is not the button, but the input.

Here the code:

```html
<div id="login-box-field"><input type="password"  id="new_password" placeholder="Password: " class="form-login myLink" title="Password"  maxlength="20">
  
</div>
```

Well, some people say something about a Form and a JS script. Please, could you tell me, how to do that? Some other samples on the platform here didn't work :(

Comment: <a *type="button"*>  ..... what?

Comment: And `<center>` doesn't exist anymore. Use CSS

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3  the type on a link is expected to be a mime type, not "button" or the likes which is valid for an <input> field.

Comment: Whats about [avoid form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818249/form-with-no-action-and-where-enter-does-not-reload-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone.

I've found the solution, which worked for me:

```html
<input class="tableInput" type="text" value="Table input" onkeypress="return tableInputKeyPress(event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function tableInputKeyPress(e){
  e=e||window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode;
  if(key==13) //Enter
  {
     //do you task here...
     return true; //return true to submit, false to do nothing
  }
}
</script>
```

Again, thank you very much to everybody who posted his solution :)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the reload of the page, you can use **e.preventDefault()** inside your function.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Example:
My HTML:

```
<a href="https://google.com" class="myLink">Click me</a>
```

JS code:

```
var myLink = document.querySelector('.myLink')
myLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your fast reply :) But could you please look on my edited question for input and send me the whole code with input tag and script tag? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery prevent default action of a (if you don't want change your html) :

```
    $("a").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**Update :** if clicking password input result is page refresh, then you need to edit that function which this input calls , so edit that function to return `false`.

Comment: Explanation is unsufficient. Could you please look on my edited question for input and send me the whole code with input tag and script tag? Thank you very much :)

Comment: sure  i'll do, yw , may you please type the function which your buttons call

Answer (score 1):

Replace anchor tag with button and add onclick() event then call the change passwaord method then it will work fine!

```
<div>
<center><button onclick="changePassword()" id="box_button" class="pw-button">Change Password</button></center></div>
<script>
function changePassword() {
alert("your code goes here")
}</script>
```

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/edx_narendra/vtu04knf/7/)

Comment: Thank you very much, but as I didn't ask for an alert this doesn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the link with `event.preventDefault()`. To prevent the link from doing anything, you should omit the `href` attribute or give it a `href` of `javascript:void(0)` or equivalently `javascript:;` and use the `onClick` event handler to perform the logic.

```html
<center><a href="javascript:;" onClick="changePassword(event)" type="button" id="box_button" class="pw-button">Change Password</a></center>
<script>
function changePassword(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("Changing password");
//other logic
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please look on my edited question for input and send me the whole code with input tag and script tag? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Tester2 What do you want? Please explain.

Comment: Hi, well I previously found this (the accepted solution) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866053/stop-reloading-page-with-enter-key, but I don't know how to embed  the JsFiddle stuff. In the script tag?  Thanks very much

Comment: @Tester2 Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m4y2boq/3/ Is it what you want?