# Hitting enter refreshes the page jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have written some code to create a to-do list using jQuery. If I hit enter it should submit the input into a list down below but the problem is that the page refreshes as if it's submitting a form. I've checked out multiple threads on SO in regards to this but I have found no solution.

[Stop reloading page with 'Enter Key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866053/stop-reloading-page-with-enter-key)

[Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

I have tried to add **e.preventDefault();** and **return: false;** which stops the refresh but also prevents the adding to the list upon hitting enter.

I have tried the following in the html form tag:

**onSubmit="return false;"**

**<form ... onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">**

**action="#"**

Is there something wrong with my IIFE that's causing this?

```js
let checklist = (function() {
  function newItem() {

    let li = $('<li></li>');
    let inputValue = $('#input').val();
    let input = $('#input');
    let deleteIcon = $('<div></div>');

    function crossOut() {
      li.toggleClass('strike');
    }

    function deleteListItem() {
      li.addClass('delete');
    }

    if (inputValue === '') {
      alert('You must write something!');
    } else {
      $('#list').append(li);
      input.val('')
    }
    
    deleteIcon.append(document.createTextNode('X'));
    li.append(deleteIcon);
    li.append(inputValue);
    
    deleteIcon.on('click', deleteListItem);
    li.on('dblclick', crossOut);

    $('#list').sortable();
  }
  
  return {
    newItemf: newItem
  };

})();

$('#button').on('click', checklist.newItemf)

$(window).on('keypress', function (e){
  if(e.which == 13) {
    checklist.newItemf;
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="toDoList">
        <input type="text" name="ListItem" id="input">
      </form>

      <div id="button">Add</div>
      <br/>
      <ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop reloading page with 'Enter Key'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866053/stop-reloading-page-with-enter-key) [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866137/1499877) explains that you need to bind the `form` `submit` event.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work unless my syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I don't fully understand why I don't need a return false;

Maybe it's that I am trying to submit the input when "enter" is keyed down instead of preventing all inputs. Thank you @isick as your answer pointed me in the right direction!

This is the code that was needed!

**$('form').on('submit', checklist.newItemf)**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to stop this is to catch the [onSubmit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) and just return false. I believe the following should be sufficient:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it also stops the add button function upon hitting enter.

Comment: If you want the form submission to behave the same as when you click the button, you can manually call click on the button `$('#button').click()` or simply invoke the same function that your click event calls `checklist.newItemf()` within the form submission handler